# TypeError: list indices must be integers, not numpy.float64

Tags: python, list, integer

I have two lists from a csv file that I simply want to subtract from one another. The error message indicates me to convert my list items to integers, they are no integers though. I tried to convert them to floats, integers, etc. none of that worked.

How can I find which data type my list currently contains? Can one not generally use float items in lists for calculation? What am I doing wrong?

Lists as printed (seem to be different data types):

```
data_WL
>>> [' 0.4001000 ', '0.3966472 ', '0.4365047', '0.4950109', '0.5348455 ', '0.5816008 ']
res_movAvWL
>>> [0.3983736, 0.41657595000000003, 0.4657578, 0.5149282, 0.55822315]
```

My code:

```
from pylab import *
import csv
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np

mymin = [] # create a new array
data_WL1 = [ float(x) for x in data_WL ] # convert items to float

for i in arange(0,len(data_WL)- (0.5 * movAvWindow),1):   
    mymin.append=((data_WL1[i]) - (res_movAvWL[i])) # data_WL - movAvWL;     detrended peak flood data
    res_WLnet = mymin[:] # create a new array which has the same items as mymin

    if int(res_WLnet[i]) < 0.8: # if netWL smaller than 0.8m print 0 in list res_WLnet, etc.
        res_WLnet.append(0)
    else:
        if int(mymin[i]) < 1.10:
            res_WLnet.append(1)
        else:
            res_WLnet.append(2)

print res_WLnet
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please try to stick to asking one question per post. I answered about your error. To be extra clear, yes you can use floats for calculations in lists. It's perfectly fine. To find out what type something is, use `isinstance(var, type)`. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549801/differences-between-isinstance-and-type-in-python) for in depth info about it.

Answer (score 3):

You actually have it backwards, the lists can contain whatever you want. But you must access them with integers. The problem is here:

```
for i in arange(0,len(data_WL)- (0.5 * movAvWindow),1):   
    mymin.append=((data_WL1[i]) - (res_movAvWL[i]))
```

You're using `i` to access the indices of the list, but notice that you use a float when determining what range `i` should iterate through. This introduce the possibility of trying to access `data_WL1[0.5]` (you're probably actually getting a different result).

Depending on what exactly your intention is for the range, you may want to use `int(len(data_WL)- (0.5 * movAvWindow))` to make sure `i` is incrementing in whole numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Try printing mymin, I bet it's empty.

You need to remove "=" from this line

```
mymin.append=((data_WL1[i]) - (res_movAvWL[i]))
```

and replace it with

```
mymin.append(data_WL1[i] - res_movAvWL[i])
```

Remarks:

- Your data_WL list needs to be converted to float as you did because it is originally a list of strings (Note the quotes)
- I don't know what is movAvWindow, if it's a number it's ok, but if it is a list make sure you're not multiplying it with a float, use

  len(movAvWindow) * 0.5

instead.

- A list may contain values with different types, if you want to check all types use:

  set([ type(x) for x in list ])

Comment: Thank you very much, both advice put me on track to solve the problem. One qustion at a time for the future.